# Facing error while loading data into Hive table from local file system

Tags: hadoop, hive

Actually I have two users in my ubuntu 12.04, one is "user" and the other is "hduser".hduser is the hadoop dedicated user.Now I have installed Hive in /usr/lib/hive/apache-hive-0.13.1-bin folder."apache-hive-0.13.1-bin" is under hduser.when I give "hive" command from hduser it is showing like this :
"No command 'hive' found".But if I give the same hive command from user,it is working fine .I'm able to create database and tables through user but I'm unable to load data into hive table.How can I resolve this problem.

Comment: Can anyone please suggest me on this issue ...

Comment: add the two lines to $HOME/.bashrc of your hduser 1.  export HIVE_HOME= /usr/lib/hive/apache-hive-0.13.1-bin   2.  export PATH=$PATH:$HIVE_HOME/bin      and   in shell do run  'source $HOME/.bashrc'

Comment: I have resolved my problem regarding path issues.Thanks for ur reply.